# Converting Android app to Java Desktop app

Tags: java, android

I developed an application in Android.  Now i want develop same application for Desktop using Java. Is there any tools or procedure to convert existing Android app code to Java Desktop app.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the application is well designed and GUI well separated from domain and other layers then this boils down to only converting android UI elements into java desktop components (SWING...)

Comment: @GETah, since VenkaReddy is asking this question, I suspect that he didn't. If this is the case, he'll have to refactor his application first, to have a clean separation.

Comment: @GETah, can you please guide me the procedure to do this.

Comment: i don't think that it is so easy... Activities aren't really meant to work well on desktop system policy...

Comment: You can run the app in Desktop using Android Emulator. No code change required.

Comment: @VenkaReddy please see my answer below

Answer (score 3):

**Android application will definitely not work on desktop computers out of the box, unless using an emulator**. However, as specified by Android documentation:

> Android platform using the Java programming language

Android uses Java. That means any java code that is well encapsulated in a domain layer independent from the android UI can be reused as part of a java desktop application. 
If the application is well designed and GUI well separated from domain and other layers, this will boil down to only converting android UI elements (eventually along with a presentation layer) into java desktop components (SWING...)

[image]